# "SimpleHTTPServer" en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

En Python 3, ¿Cuál sería el equivalente a `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mira la documentación [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

```
python -m http.server
```